# Store multiple user form submissions to an array and store the array in a table

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, userform

I have seen the following question here: [How to add multiple data rows at once from UserForm to Excel DataBase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33627391/how-to-add-multiple-data-rows-at-once-from-userform-to-excel-database) which appears to be a solution to my question.

However, I am experiencing some difficulties when trying to implement the above solution.

**Background:**
I want to create a userform that allows me to add stock information such as: market, symbol, currency, price and quantity of stocks and add these to a table.

**Attempt:**

Here is the user form I have designed (very simple currently)

[image: Initial Userform]

[image: Portfolio]

I would like to store multiple submissions and then add all submissions to the table.

**Code**

*Module1*

```
Public ws As Worksheet
Public DataA()
```

*Userform Code*

```
    '----Code to Set the dimension of the Data array
Private Sub UserForm1_Initialize()
    Dim DataA(5, 0)
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Portfolio")
    '----Rest of your code
End Sub

'----Code to add a data set to the data array

'Button to add is called cmd_add
'Text Boxes are names: txt_SM, txt_Sy, txt_Cu, txt_Pr and txt_Qu
'These represent the desired headings: Stock Market, Symbol, Currency, Price and Quantity



Private Sub cmd_add_Click()

    DataA(1) = UserForm1.txt_SM
    DataA(2) = UserForm1.txt_Sy
    DataA(3) = UserForm1.txt_Cu
    DataA(4) = UserForm1.txt_Pr
    DataA(5) = UserForm1.txt_Qu

    ReDim Preserve DataA(LBound(DataA, 1) To UBound(DataA, 1), LBound(DataA, 2) To UBound(DataA, 2) + 1)
End Sub
```

However, after attempting to add a submission I get a "Subscript Out of Range Error". It appears to be an issue with the array DataA but I'm not sure where the error is. I have declared it as a public array in a separate module and have specified the dimensions in the initialisation step.

Any help on solving this issue and get working would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `cmd_add_Click()` you need to use 2 indexes for the array...

```
DataA(1, 0) = UserForm1.txt_SM
```

***UPDATE***

After seeing your workbook, I suggest you change your code to this...

```
Private Sub cmd_add_Click()

    ReDim d(1 To 1, 1 To 5)

    With UserForm1
        d(1, 1) = .txt_SM
        d(1, 2) = .txt_Sy
        d(1, 3) = .txt_Cu
        d(1, 4) = .txt_Pr
        d(1, 5) = .txt_Qu
    End With

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Portfolio").[a1].End(xlDown).Offset(1).Resize(, 5) = d

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I thought I may have bee able to just use the single index. Unfortunately I am still getting the error. Do you know of any other reasons this may happen?

Comment: DataA(1, 0) = <Subscript out of range>

Comment: You need to post more of the code. Or send me the workbook.

Comment: I'm happy to send you the workbook. Do you have a preferred method to receive it?

Comment: Thanks, I've sent that now. Hopefully the issue is relatively simple to solve.

Comment: Thanks! That has worked. Really appreciate your help on this one.